# Preparing a question / answer privately

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I do not want to answer immediately – or rather: I start an answer, and then realise that I do not have enough time for the moment. Currently, I can

1. leave the window open, but this is not very reliable
2. save the text somehow clumsily (and then forget where I saved it)
3. post an incomplete or bad answer and improve it later

It would be ideal to have a fourth option:

4. implicitly save it on SO as a "pending" answer or similar.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow already provides this facility. When you type something into the box, you can watch next to the "Post Your Answer" button and there will be a "draft saved" text that flashes. You will know if it is saved because there will be a "discard" link there.

[image: Discard draft]

I don't know exactly how long the draft is kept for, but I've come back to a question a day later and my drafted answer was still there, so it's an adequate amount of time.

I've typed things in Notepad before. I have an entire folder dedicated to anything Stack Overflow so I always know where the stuff is at.

Comment: Wow +1! ... yes now that you mention it, I have seen that "discard" text too. Maybe I will wait to get some more confirmation on this.  At least, it is not saved all the time...